# How to allow Socket IO requests on Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, socket.io

I have a web app running on a Amazon EC2 Instance on port 8080, the webapp while starting, starts a Socket io server listening on port 9092.

in the client file connecting to the Socket io server i have this:

```
io.connect('http://<IPADDRESS>:9092');
```

Unfortunately, this request is getting blocked as shown [image: socket.io requests blocked]:

I thought the problem was about inbound rules of my EC2 instance, i therefore allowed traffic for the purpose as shown:
[image: Ec2 instance inbound rules]

But the requests are still blocked...

**NOTE:** When my app is hosted locally, everything works fine.

So why is amazon behaving this way and what am i supposed to do to come across this issue?

**UPDATE:**

`netstat -a -n | grep 9092` outputs this on instance:

[image: netstat output on port 9092]

Also have a look on what firefox shows me about a request attempt timings:

[image: socketio request timings]

Comment: "Amazon" is not "behaving this way."  They don't have hidden rules to block things.   There's something you've configured incorrectly but there is not enough information shown here to illustrate the problem.  When you say the connection is "blocked" you are saying more than you are showing here.  It's not succeeding, sure, but what is the justification for specifically saying it is "blocked?"  What does `netstat -a -n | grep 9092` show, on the instance?

Comment: thanks @Michael-sqlbot for commenting, i have updated my question. Thanks for having a look on it.

Comment: It looks like your `socket.io` server is bound to the local interface, which can't be reached externally. Can you share the code that sets up the `socket.io` server?

Comment: thanks @robertklep, i've bound the server to my ec2 ipaddress and everything is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns that i was binding my server to the localhost address, as if it were accessed from the localhost.

Thanks to @robertklep comment, i did bound the server to the ec2 instance address and it's working now.

Comment: I am doing something similar just that I am trying to communicate between two EC2 instances and seeing a "Gateway Timeout Error"

Comment: How do you bound the server to the ec2 instance address???

Comment: Downvoting since you didn't give any explicit steps to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to establish a socket connection with your server from outside of EC2 is to listen to all the incoming traffic:

```
server.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');
```

This is only recommended for testing and development environment. Do not use this for production.